# Ruby on Rails Installation process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

So first i installed the Ruby 2.2.1 x 64 version installer 
from this site 
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

And then  using the command line

```
gem install rails
```

and then i downloaded  devkit  and install it

```
DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
```

Then started creating rails app

```
rails new app -d mysql
```

but there's an error while starting the server

```
rails server
```

it says:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysq
l2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/li
b/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/li
b/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/li
b/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.rb
:134:in `require'
        from c:/Users/JOEY/readit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

please help!

Comment: Are there any errors after running `bundle install` ?

Comment: None actually when i execute the rails new app -d mysql i didn't need to run 'bundle install'  Am i right?

Comment: Nope, it runs automatically if you don't cancel. Try to uninstall and reinstall mysql2 gem

Comment: Required full backtrace of error to investigate your problem.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, it definitely looks like an MySQL error to me. Then again, I thought my newbish mistake was a problem with Rails... I had a problem like this, except on Mac... let me dig up my question from somewhere... never mind, seemed to be a problem with my use of RubyMine, hope you figure out a solution!